# Error on condition between df col values - python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to setup some control logic that executes different tasks based on two df columns. Below, I have two applicable df cols that contain integers. If `df.b` is > `df.a` I want to execute additional code. Otherwise, I want the func to pass.

But I'm getting an error.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'b': [1,3,2,3,4],
                    })

for x in df['b']:

    if x > df['a']:

        print(x)
        # do something else
        
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: What is the "*do something else*"?

Comment: Additional filtering and then sending a notification

Comment: Then better filter first, then loop over the rows: `df2 = df[df['b']>df['a']]` and work on `df2`